# yii2 pagecahe array dependecny

Tags: caching, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am implementing page cache for one of my page. For depenedency, I have to check an array, which can be either exist or not. Possible array keys cane ,
usersearch['id'], usersearch['name'], usersearch['phone]. I have to add dependency for any change in these values as well.
Also, I have to clear cache for any update or add in user table.
Is there any possible solution for this.?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use **variations**

public function behaviors(){

```
    $usersearch = Yii::$app->requst->get('usersearch');
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
            'only' => ['index'],
            'duration' => 60,
            'variations' => [
                 'YOUR_DYNAMIC_VALUE1','YOUR_DYNAMIC_VALUE2'
            ],
            'dependency' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Ref [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-page)

IN YOUR CASE ,you can use

```
'variations' => \Yii::$app->requst->get('usersearch')??[],
```

or

```
'variations' => [
    \/Yii::$app->requst->get('usersearch')['id'] ?? '',
    \Yii::$app->requst->get('usersearch')['name'] ?? '',
    \Yii::$app->requst->get('usersearch')['phone'] ?? '',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `yii\caching\FileCache` component with the following configuration.

Firstly, you set the cache in the `init` function of your controller:

```
Yii::$app->setComponents([
   'yourCacheName' => [
       'class' => \yii\caching\FileCache::class,
       'defaultDuration' => 1800, //cache duration in seconds
       'keyPrefix' => Yii::$app->getSession()->getId(). '_'
   ]
]);
```

Here, the parameter `keyPrefix` is set so that it is linked to the session ID. Thus, the visitors do not see each other's cached page. If the content is static and equal, regardless of the user or the session, this parameter can be removed.

In the view that must be cached you can call the `beginCache` function and the dependency as follows:

```
$this->beginCache('cache-id', [
    'cache' => Yii::$app->yourCacheName, // the name of the component as set before
    'variations' => [
       $usersearch['id'] ?? '',
       $usersearch['name'] ?? '',
       $usersearch['phone'] ?? '',        
    ],
    'dependency' => [
       'class' => \yii\caching\DbDependency::class,
       'sql' => 'SELECT count(*) FROM your_user_table'
    ]
]);

// your view


$this->endCache();
```